Conditions for a Random Variable to Satisfy a Probability Bound on Boundary Points.
Let  $X$ be a random variable supported on $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and let $\mathcal{X}$ be compact. Consider $ f $ as the probability density of $ X $.
My question is: What conditions must $ X $ satisfy in order to ensure that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\mathbb{P}(X \in B_{h}(x))=\infty \tag{1}
$$
where $ x $ belongs to the boundary of $\mathcal{X}$ and $ h $ is of the form $ h=\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)^{1/(d+4)} $?
By conditions, I mean those commonly encountered in statistics and probability, such as conditions on the tails or moments, among others that are typical in statistical contexts.
In the 1-dimensional case, I have verified condition (1) for several probability densities, for instance, certain Beta distributions, and found that condition (1) is satisfied. I believe that in the 1-dimensional case, condition (1) will generally be satisfied and that distributions where it is not satisfied will be quite rare.
